# Array function in SML

Tags: arrays, sml

I'm creating the union find algorithm using persistent arrays. Here are some functions I can use:

```
Array.sub : 'a array * int -> 'a
Array.update: 'a array * int * 'a -> unit
```

I need to build a table

```
 datatype 'a table = Array of 'a Array.array | Change of int * 'a * 'a table ref
```

from an existing one that differs just one slot in a constant time, using the Change constructor and the library

```
Array.tabulate : int * (int-> 'a)-> 'a array
```

implement the function that returns a reference to a table of size n where each element is its own partition.

```
newTable : int -> int table ref
```

Here is my attempt but any help would be appreciated because I'm really confused:

```
fun newTable n = 
        if 0 = Array.sub(Array.tabulate (n,fn i => i), 0) 
            then () 
        else 
           ref(Change(Array.array(n)));
```

Comment: What exactly is the function `newTable` supposed to do?

Comment: I have once implemented union-find according to the Algorithms book by Robert Sedgewick https://github.com/gruenewa/sml-snippets/blob/master/unionfind/union-find.sml

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but I'll try to answer from what I think your problem wants you to do.

If you look at the `newTable` signature, you can see that it takes an `int` on input, and returns a `int table ref`. Your solution returns `unit`, so that doesn't typecheck.

The goal of `newTable` is to return a ref on a table of integers different from each other. You already understand that you can build an array of different (increasing) integers using `Array.tabulate`. But you must retrun a `table`, not an `array`. The definition of the `table` datatype tells us how to produce it using an `array`, so all you have to do is wrap up the array you produced likeso:

```
fun newTable n = 
    ref (Array (Array.tabulate (n,fn i => i)))
```

The `newTable` function is the equivalent of the *MakeSet* operation described in the [Union Find WP article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-Find), improved to produce a whole set rather than a singleton.